# Control Google Music with keyboard media keys in Chrome with Logitech SetPoint 5.80.4

Tags: google-chrome, logitech-keyboard, google-music

I'm a Google Music user and a big fan. I have a Logitech MK710 keyboard & mouse setup, together with SetPoint driver 5.80.4 (Control Center v6.65.62). I would like to be able to use the media keys of my keyboard to control Google Music in Chrome (v37.0.2062.124 m) on Windows 7.

Now, though the media keys of my keyboard work fine with Windows Media Player, but they do nothing in Google Music on Chrome. I've tried to use several Chrome extensions, to no avail.

Also, I've manually entered the keyboard buttons in the Chrome quick key menu (don't know if it's the right terminology in English):

[image: Chrome Quick Key Menu]

I've noticed that sometimes (not  all the times) when I disable SetPoint (and thus lose all functionality of SetPoint), the media buttons DO work. However, I want it to work all the time and with setpoint enabled.

Does anyone have a clue on how to fix this issue?

P.S.: I've seen some kind of workaround for SetPoint to control Spotify, but Google Chrome is different in that it has no separate client. The workaround is done via the player.ini file
[How do I get my Logitech media buttons to control Spotify](https://superuser.com/questions/338108/how-do-i-get-my-logitech-media-buttons-to-control-spotify)

Can anyone, maybe Logitech even, give some insights? I tried posting on their support forums, but I cannot register for some technical reasons...

Comment: Just a follow up, please note that the media keys do not work in other browsers either.

Answer (score 4):

Seems like it's a problem with Logitech SetPoint:

http://forums.logitech.com/t5/Keyboards-and-Keyboard-Mice/Control-Google-Play-Music-with-Media-Keys/td-p/1242070

If you don't use any of the specific functions on the keyboard you can install generic keyboard drivers instead.

Or uninstall Logitech SetPoint (if you don't use it for mouse settings, I would do this)

Comment: Seems like we have to wait for Logitech to acknowledge and solve the problem. If their support forums would work at least...

Comment: Unfortunately the link doesn't work anymore, but it prompted me to search, and it seems there is a fix, posting as separate answer.

Answer (score 4):

Experiencing the same issue, I got to this thread via Google, and following @LimDul's answer, being a 2 year old answer, I searched the Logitech forums once more.

I found the following [forum entry](https://community.logitech.com/s/question/0D53100005100nNCAQ/chrome-mediakeys-and-logitech-setpoint-v667-and-older-version-too-final-fix) which indicated there is a solution:

> ... found indeed a really EASY fix to make MediaKeys working with Chrome without the need to run Chrome as Administrator or uninstalling SetPoint software.
>
> You can find the fix here: http://steinerd.com/developments/hacks/media-keys/
>
> ...

The link points to a blog post that explains how the SetPoint's `players.ini` file can be modified to add Google Chrome's Google Play Music app to the list of supported players.

The credit goes entirely to Anthony Steiner the poster of the blog.

I'm copying it below:

> There is a file in a directory:
>   `C:\Program Files\Logitech\SetPointP\players.ini`
>   and this is where 100% of the magic happens for this little hack of ours.
>
> This file has a large amount of Media Players already configured for it… and since my hack is mainly functioning guesswork you should tack the following edits near the bottom of each `[Section]` of the INI file.
>
> > ```
> > [Players]
> > GooglePlayMusic=key,chrome.exe,Chrome_WidgetWin_1,xxx,xxx,&0xB3,&0xB3,&0xB2,&0xB1,&0xB0,0,1,Google Play Music
> >
> > [Players.Run]
> > GooglePlayMusic=path,%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Web Applications\_crx_icppfcnhkcmnfdhfhphakoifcfokfdhg\Google Play Music.ico
> >
> > [Players.Display]
> > GooglePlayMusic=Google Play Music
> > ```
>
> REMEMBER: You’re going to want to take each one of those and put them at the bottom of each respective section of the existing players.ini file.
>
> You’ll have to close SetPoint from the task manager or exit it from the context-menu via the notification icons on your Windows Taskbar.
>
> Open “Mouse and Keyboard Settings”, should be a green icon.  Open up the Keyboard menu, you’ll see Google Play Music in the list of media players.
>
> Note:  I couldn’t get the dang thing to open Play Music directly; but this little hack will allow you to use your keyboard’s Media Keys > with SetPoint running and should work with both Windowed and Tabbed instances of the Google Play Music.